# Getting LazyInitializationException "could not initialize proxy - no Session" when running a transaction in a background thread

Tags: multithreading, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a strange problem:

Say I have two Entity classes, e.g. `Container` and `ContainedObject`. `Container` has a `@OneToMany` relationship to `ContainedObject`.

When getting the contained objects directly, everything works fine, but when running from a background thread, I get "could not initialize proxy - no Session".

Example:

```
@Component
public class Something {

    @Autowired
    private ContainerRepository _repo;

    public void doInForeground() {
        Container container = _repo.findOne(42L); // suppose 42 exists
        container.getContainedObjects().size(); // succeeds
    }

    public void submitToBackground() {
        CompletableFuture<Void> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doInBackground());
    }

    private Void doInBackground() {
        Container container = _repo.findOne(42L);
        container.getContainedObjects().size(); // throws LazyInitializationException
    }
}
```

The `ContainerRepository` is a `PagingAndSortingRepository`. Running `doInForeground`succeeds, but `submitToBackground` throws the well-known `LazyInitializationException` "could not initialize proxy - no Session"

It seems as if no transaction is started or it is closed too fast. Annotating any of the methods with `@Transactional` does not help either.

Is it simply not possible to use Spring-JPA in background threads or is any additional magic needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need a readOnly transaction to get lazy collections.

2) I suppose that @Transactional doesn't work on your local methods because when you call a local method you call the implementation directly, not a proxy object created by Spring.

If it's the case there are at least 2 choices:

1) Switch to Aspectj

```
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

2) Create a transaction manually using TransactionTemplate inside `doInForeground()`:
http://simplespringtutorial.com/springProgrammaticTransactions.html

Comment: 3. choice would be to push the executing method into another class so that proxying will work.

Comment: @Martin Frey Yes, it's also the case. Thanks

Comment: @Martin Frey: What do you mean with "push to another class"? Autowire another class into my "Something" and put the method there? / Multisync: How to write the AspectJ XML snippet above in Java? I'm going completely annotation driven without any XML.

Comment: @rabejens Regarding another class - yes, you can create another class and put Transactional annotated method there. Switching to Aspectj can have some side effects (for example people write negative things about performance). And I don't know how to do that with annotations. So I'd recommend to refactor your code to call a transactional method from another class or manage transactions programmatically. Aspectj I'd consider as an extreme measure.